# Pretérito perfeito do conjuntivo vs. Pretérito imperfeito do conjuntivo

Tags: gramática

Quando eu estava a estudar os modos verbais, apercebi-me que o uso do pretérito perfeito composto do conjuntivo pode ser facilmente confundido com o uso daquele imperfeito. Eu já sei que o imperfeito do conjuntivo se refere a ações presentes inconcretizáveis. Mas já que as expressões que lhe determinam o uso são quase as mesmas do imperfeito, deparo-me com tanta confusão quando o pretérito perfeito se utiliza com a conjunção "embora", por exemplo.

Qual é a diferença entre os exemplos abaixo, de uma perspetiva temporal?

"Embora *estivesse* doente, fui trabalhar."
"Embora ele já *tenha saído* há muito tempo, ainda não chegou a casa."

Grato antecipadamente.